# Getting error during update SQL query single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 tables "HOF" and "WE_GROUP_HOF_K"

In "HOF" table total "2066666" records

In "WE_GROUP_HOF_K" table total "116" records

I have SQL query who find duplicate cnicno column with hofid column from 2 tables "HOF" and "WE_GROUP_HOF_K"

This query found total "120" duplicate cnicno records

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT hofid, cnicno
     FROM hof 
    WHERE cnicno IN (SELECT cnic_no FROM we_group_hof_k);
```

In "WE_GROUP_HOF_K" table there are 1 empty column "GROUP_HOF_ID". Now I want to update duplicate records of "HOFID" column into "GROUP_HOF_ID" column

I am getting this error while update records:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

**Update SQL Query:**

```
UPDATE we_group_hof_k wg
 SET wg.GROUP_HOF_ID =
      (SELECT h.hofid
         FROM hof h
        WHERE h.cnicno = wg.cnic_no);
```

Answer (score 0):

If all `CNICNO`s share the same `HOFID`, then use `DISTINCT`:

```
UPDATE we_group_hof_k wg
 SET wg.GROUP_HOF_ID =
      (SELECT DISTINCT h.hofid           --> here
         FROM hof h
        WHERE h.cnicno = wg.cnic_no);
```

If not, which `HOFID` do you want to take? `MIN` or `MAX` would also help, e.g.

```
UPDATE we_group_hof_k wg
 SET wg.GROUP_HOF_ID =
      (SELECT MIN(h.hofid)               --> here
         FROM hof h
        WHERE h.cnicno = wg.cnic_no);
```